# time optimize way to insert/update a thousands rows in codeigniter 4 using insert or update batch?

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert, bulkinsert, codeigniter-4

I can insert 8000 rows at that time using insert batch but there are more time run so

what should I do for time consuming using below query? my query like this

$Model->insertBatch($array, null, count($array));

Comment: Show us some sample source code.  What's your configured *batch size*?

Comment: hey @steven7mwesigwa could you please tell me  what about config batch size in detail

Thanks for your replay

Comment: insertBatch([$set = null[, $escape = null[, $batch_size = 100]]]) https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insertbatch#insertBatch

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa yes i have use this type of example but speed is not optimize..